# Long-timespan novel with baseball focus

Tags: story-identification, novel

Something recently jogged part of a memory of a novel I once read, and now I'm trying to track it down.  I don't remember much of it, so it's possible I'm conflating more than one book, but what is coming to mind is that it was about a group of un-aging, immortal children (or teens?), set primarily in the late 19th and/or early 20th centuries.  The theme that's sticking in my mind the most was baseball, and how it evolved over the "kid's" lifetime.  It may have been a series, and I think that by the end the kids started aging normally, but I forget why.

I probably read this in the 2000s, give or take a year or two.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the web series [17776](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/17776), although that was about (American) football.